# SQL query to indicate presence of a corresponding row

Tags: sql

Assuming tables A and B, how do I write a query that would return all columns of A and a flag indicating the presence of a corresponding child row in B

For example:

col1_a|col2_a|...|hasrowinb

Comment: can you elaborate on "corresponding child row"? is it a row that has the same primary key, has all the same elements, has a specific set of the same elements, or what?  what is the condition under which `hasrowinb` is true?

Comment: @ewok - table B has a fk into A, nothing more.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Just one more question, is there a consensus on what performs better, a subquery or a join?

Comment: That will depend greatly on what database engine you are using.  Newer versions of SQL Server, at least, have a pretty good query analyzer that can usually pick the best query plan either way, but I don't know about other engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the following is the "simplest" way of doing the query, while guaranteeing that there are no duplicates:

```
select a.*,
       (case when 0 = (select count(*) from b where b.aid = a.aid)
             then 'N'
             else 'Y'
        end) as hasRowInB
from a
```

Comment: Won't this have poor performance compared to a join.  (sub-query for each row.)  I guess some engines will optimize it?

Comment: @Hogan - I'm using Postgres and when I tried EXPLAIN ANALYZE, I see the total time seems to fluctuate widely on all the solutions on this page. Not sure what to make of the cost (a rather wide range on Gordon's approach, and a rather small one in yours!).

Comment: @rebnoob - exactly my point, In Gordon's for each row in a it does a select from b so you O(ab). In mine it does two selects so you get O(a+b).  The downside of mine is you can get multiple rows for a if the relationship is not 1-to-1.  This can be solved with a DISTINCT as JTC pointed out.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that Hogan. As much as I'd like to go with Gordon's approach (it's just easy to read and I've a dozen or so similar flags, makes copy and pasting easy!) I guess, I'll go with yours/Curtis's solution. I can't wrap my mind around JTC's solution, yet! Thanks again everyone. Btw, is it too late to change the "accepted answer"?

Answer (score 2):

Given that b is a child row if b.a_id = a.id then this will work.

Adjust the join to your definition of child.

```
SELECT a.*, CASE WHEN b.id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS hasrowinb
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id
```

Answer (score 1):

This will makes sure duplicates aren't created for Table A for each matching record of TableB.

```
SELECT a.*, b.HasRowInB
FROM TableA a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT a.id, CASE COUNT(b.id) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as HasRowInB
    FROM TableA a
    LEFT JOIN TableB b on a.id = b.a_id
    GROUP BY a.id
) b on a.id = b.id
```

Comment: You'd have to sit down for a bit to figure which one is faster. Probably depends on what the data set looks like more than anything.

Comment: in my experience the only way to determine faster is to benchmark.  hardware configuration, etc can make a huge difference.